# Проверка cursor на пустоту

Tags: android

```
  // вывод в лог данных из курсора
  void logCursor(Cursor c, String title) {
    if (c != null) {
      if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, title + ". " + c.getCount() + " rows");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        do {
          sb.setLength(0);
          for (String cn : c.getColumnNames()) {
            sb.append(cn + " = "
                + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(cn)) + "; ");
          }
          Log.d(LOG_TAG, sb.toString());
        } while (c.moveToNext());
      }
    } else
      Log.d(LOG_TAG, title + ". Cursor is null");
  }
```

Зачем if(c!=null), если if (c.moveToFirst()) вернет false в случае если cursor будет null

Comment: Если у вас курсор == null , то метод moveToFirst() - выбросит NullReferenceException. Видимо для этого и есть проверка на null

Comment: moveToFirst() выдаст вам не false, а NPE, если курсор будет null. Как вы представляете себе вызов метода, если объекта не существует?

Answer (score 1):

1) В функции реализован функционал проверки входных параметров.
Метод может принять следующие параметры logCursor(null,null), если не будет проверки if (c != null), то вы получите NPE на строке c.moveToFirst().

2) В строчка кода if (c.moveToFirst()) просит курсор перейти на первую доступную строку в сформированном Cursor, если это удалось true, иначе false. (Если в Cursor нет выборки, то будет тоже false)